# Wildcard Forward with Exception of a Few Addresses

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to move my domain from example.com to example.dev and also set a wildcard forward. I use WordPress for blogging, now I want all posts and pages to be moved to the new address but I want some pages to remain accessible with my previous address. For example:

```
example.com/post -> example.dev/post
example.com/post2 -> example.dev/post2
[all posts be redirected]
example.com/page1 -> example.dev/page1
example.com/page2 -> example.dev/page2
[...]
example.com/pageN -> example.com/pageN (remain Same URL)
example.com/PageX -> accessible from both domains
```

Also, if someone accesses `page2` with the new domain (like example.dev/page2) it should be redirected to the previous domain (example.com/page2).

I can't figure how to do it in `htaccess` or any other way. I should mention that I don't have `SSH` access to the server. It's a shared host with multiple sites in it.

I checked and people have had the same issue but with two WordPress installations, I want it to be done on my existing, singular, WordPress site.

Comment: Well, you write that you "can't figure how to do it", but you do not post your current attempt here. How do you expect us to assist with it then? Please understand that we are not here to implement a solution for you, we are not a free coding service, but we are here to help you find your own solution. So please add your current attempt to the question and point out what is currently working and what is not. Thanks.

Comment: arkascha, I understand. I tried few plugins in WordPress (such as [redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)) but so far I was unsuccessful. I'm not a sysadmin or programmer. I also searched for htaccess codes but none was suitable for my issue. Sorry if my question is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in summary:

- Two domains point to the same website: `example.com` and `example.dev`
- Some URLs should only be accessible at `example.com` (redirect if not).
- Some URLs should be accessible at both domains (no redirect)
- Otherwise, redirect all requests to `example.dev`.

Try the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller.

We can use a `TARGET_DOMAIN` environment variable to set which domain (if any) a particular URL should be accessible through and then use this later to trigger the redirect.

```
# Prevent rewritten requests (to the WP front-controller) from being redirected
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# The TARGET_DOMAIN environment variable holds the desired target domain (if any)
#  - for the requested URL
# eg. "example.com" or "example.dev" or empty for no redirect / accessible from both.

# Set the "default" target domain
#  - Any URLs not listed below will redirect to this domain
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN:example.dev]

# URLs that should be redirected to (or remain at) the other domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bio [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/computing [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/contact [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/donate [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/encrypt [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/genderless-pronouns [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gnu-linux-controversy [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/legal [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/readings [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/now
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN:example.com]

# URLs that should not be redirected - accessible from both domains
#  - Sets TARGET_DOMAIN to empty string (ie. no target domain)
#  - Must also exclude static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.) from being redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|css|js|jpg|gif|webp)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN]

# Redirect to the desired TARGET_DOMAIN (if any)
#  - if not already at the TARGET_DOMAIN
RewriteCond %{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} !^([a-z0-9.-]+)@@\1$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Additional explanation:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bio [OR]
> ```

I've gone back to using a regular expression (regex) match. This gives you greatest flexible at the expense of additional complexity (although you can mix the two). The above matches any URL that *starts with* `/bio`. So, it will also match `/bio/` and `/bioanything`. Use an end-of-string anchor (`$`) to match `/bio` only. eg. `^/bio$`.

Using a regex will be required to avoid redirecting any URL that *starts* `/wp-admin`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|css|js|jpg|gif|webp)$ [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_DOMAIN]
> ```

Note that in addition to certain requested URLs (`/login`, `/admin`, etc.) static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.) also need to be excluded from being redirected.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} .
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN} !^([a-z0-9.-]+)@@\1$
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{ENV:TARGET_DOMAIN}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
> ```

The first *condition* ensures we only try to redirect when there is a target domain set. The second *condition* checks to see whether the currently requested domain (ie. the `Host` header) is different to the `TARGET_DOMAIN`. If both of these checks are successful then it redirects to the target domain on the same URL.

Make sure your browser cache is clear before testing and test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.